# Xamarin.Forms log changes to bound data

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, event-handling

For testing and learning I have created a Xamarin.forms app containing a listview bound to a SQlite database. The xaml is like this:

```
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Switch IsToggled="{Binding switchState}" />
                         </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The codebehind binds the ListView.ItemsSource to a list of items populated by Database.GetItemsAsync().

The model is straightforward:

```
public class Item
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool switchState { get; set; }
}
```

I want to log a timestamp to a different table every time the user changes the switch. How can I hook into the binding to accomplish this?

Pitfall #1: the switchState column can also be written into by other parts of the business logic. But in that case, I don't want those changes logged. That's why I cannot use a simple set routine in the model, since this would always log.

Pitfall #2: Through the database binding any change to the underlying database does also propagate to the view, right?. Like in #1, changes appearing in the view because of changes to the underlying database are not to be logged.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch has a `Toggled` event, so in your codebehind you can create a method like this:

```
private void HandleSwitchToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    // log the timestamp to your database
}
```

and then in your xaml,

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding switchState}"
        Toggled="HandleSwitchToggled" />
```

As for updating the database and having your view update, the view is not bound to the database, but instead bound to the `List<Item>` that was returned from a database call. So if you want to update the view, you will need to directly update the `List<Item>` (and, if necessary, update the database as well, though again updating the database won't affect the view).

On a side note, you shouldn't bind the `ListView` to the `List<item>` in your code-behind; you should instead do that in the view model.

Comment: Thanx for the hint, it worked right away. Regarding your comment ... you are definitely right, for real MVVM I'd be supposed to do so, but frankly speaking I have great difficulties to get MVVM implemented. Knowing how it works is not really sufficient to get working code, and boy, this whole MVVM thing is way over-engineered and over-compluicated (for me at my current level) while also beeing under-documented, so for the moment I'll go with my app the way it is.